# Open html page in tab with that website already open

Tags: c#

I've seen some application do this before. But how is it possible to open a html file up in a certain tab in chrome with that website already open. So lets say we check that we have `http://localhost:70/` open on `index.html`, but we now want to open `about.html` in that tab.

I am using `C#` for anyone who doesn't want to look in the tag. As in I would usually use

```
Process.Start(filePath);
```

Comment: with an anchor tag? <a href="about.html">about</a>

Comment: Read the question and tags.